# Why is my Internet Explorer8 opening multiple tabs with one click

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

When I use ctrl+mouse, or use the scroller to click a link. I got two or three new Internet Explorer tabs open, does anyone know how to fix this. It happens on my Chrome too. My lap top is Windows 7 64-bit.

Also, how can I restore the Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7?

Comment: Your question is more appropriate for superuser.

Comment: Are you sure your mouse isn't just touchy?  And what do you mean by 'restore the IE8'?

Comment: You should upgrade to IE9. It is substantially more user friendly and prevents third-party applications and add-ons from causing this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

couple things to check in IE Tools>Internet Options.
[image]

make sure you only see one site for your home page. then press the settings button
[image]

checking "Open only the first home page when Internet Explorer starts" will suppress duplicate tabs. But look at all of these and how they impact your experience.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For my users, the number one cause of this is a defective mouse.  I use the built-in calculator (calc.exe on Windows) to verify mouse functionality.

For restoring IE8, simply go to Control Panel->Programs and Features->View Installed Updates and uninstall the IE entries (after IE is uninstalled it will default to IE8)